# What are the data type limitations of the POST and GET HTML Form Methods?

Tags: html, forms, post, types, get

What are the data type limitations of the POST and GET HTML Form Methods? Are you limited to passing only specific data types like--strings, integers, floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST and GET both submit strings to the server. It is up to your program to determine how to parse that data. Most frameworks give you a basis to do this already that support most primitive datatypes. In the case of ASP.NET MVC, it can bind to most objects.

Comment: So I would have to do a work around if I wanted to submit a class or an array?

Comment: That completely depends on what framework you are using. In ASP.NET MVC, the ModelBinder will take care of binding your data to a class. It is based on naming conventions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405.aspx

Comment: I am using PHP with no other framework when what is involved with the initial install.

Comment: Well in that case you will have to go into the $_POST array and get the variables out on your own and convert them to your datatype. There are a number of MVC frameworks for PHP - I would suggest that you use one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961669/php-mvc-framework

Answer (score 0):

Of what I'm aware, there's no data type limitations, but there's another limitation. GET has a [maximum length that varies between browsers](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html). As a general rule, I use POST for form submissions that doesn't require that the user should be able to bookmark or send the URL to someone.