# Sending JS date object to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date

I'm sending JS date object to PHP in ajax. Then I write it to mySql.
Should I convert date object to string in javascript before sending? Or can I convert it in PHP - I prefer this solution.
Which way is correct one?

PS. I'm using PDO to write it in DB.

Comment: you can't send "code" objects through ajax. one way or another, you're serializing your JS date object into a string, so might as well serialize it into something easy to parse, e.g. a unix timestamp (which in JS is in milliseconds).

Comment: You can't send objects, so either way it's going to be a string when it reaches the server.

Comment: Keep them as intergers of _some unit_ since the unix epoch

Comment: send timestamp... like `Date.now()` or `(new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: Regardless of which way you send your date it will be a string. You can do it in any format as long you know how you will parse back into a date that can be parsed by your db engine of choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases **you will have to** convert your JS Date to string. 
Good ways are:

```
var d = new date();
var iso_date_string = d.toISOString(); 
// produces "2014-12-15T19:42:27.100Z"
var locale_date_string = d.toLocaleDateString();
// produces "12/15/2014"
```

`toLocaleDateString()` has a lot of localization options.

And you can convert any valid date string to date in PHP by

```
$date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2014-12-15T19:42:27.100Z") );
// produces "2014-12-15 20:42:27"
$date = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime("12/15/2014") );
// 2014-12-15
```

`"Y-m-d H:i:s"` or `Y-m-d` can be [any supported date and/or time format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Answer (score 0):

POST and GET both submit strings to the server, read answer here: [What are the data type limitations of the POST and GET HTML Form Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002727/what-are-the-data-type-limitations-of-the-post-and-get-html-form-methods)

However in practice whether you must manually convert depends on your framework, for example [jQuery will convert objects to strings for you](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) before sending to server (sounds like what you want).

Still other end-to-end frameworks may handle data binding in such a way that you don't need to manually convert either in browser or on server.